# Makes table td editable after clicking "Edit" btn in Angular?

Tags: html, angularjs, contenteditable

Im trying to create a table with repeaters include 3 buttons to control the table (edit,delete,save).

This is my HTML:

```
                <tr data-ng-repeat="d in pnl.Rows" data-ng-readonly="false">
                    <td contenteditable="false" data-info="datafield" data-ng-repeat="val in d | limitObjectTo: (pnl.Head).length">{{val}}</td>
                    <td data-info="controlbtn" >
                        <span style="font-size:18px; margin-left:5px" class="ion-close-round cr-icon-link"></span>
                        <span style="font-size:18px; margin-left:5px" class="ion-edit cr-icon-link"></span>
                        <span style="font-size:18px;" class="ion-checkmark-round cr-icon-link"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

As you can see, 
I need to create func for those span icon which will turn those td to editable (except the td of the icons).

I tried unluckly this one:

```
    $scope.enableEditable = function (r) {

       $(this).find("td").each(function () {
          console.log("asdas");
          alert($("td").val);
          if($("td").hasAttribute("contenteditable"))
          {
             $attr.contenteditable = "true";
           }
      });

}
```

Comment: Where did you get this attribute `contenteditable` from?

Comment: you want your buttons to act like an link to edit your options, right?